# beautiful soup parser can't find links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I was trying to parse an HTML document to find links using `Beautiful Soup` and found a weird behavior. The page is http://people.csail.mit.edu/gjtucker/ . Here's my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

user_agent = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17'}

t=requests.get(url, headers = user_agent).text

soup=BeautifulSoup(t, 'html.parser')
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print link['href']
```

This prints two links: `http://www.amazon.jobs/team/speech-amazon` and `https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=-gJkPHIAAAAJ&hl=en`, whereas clearly there are many more links in the page.

Can anyone reproduce this? Is there a specific reason for this happening with this URL? A few outher urls worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML of the page is not well-formed, you should use a [more lenient parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser), like `html5lib`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(t, 'html5lib')
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link['href'])
```

Prints:

```
http://www.amazon.jobs/team/speech-amazon
https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=-gJkPHIAAAAJ&hl=en
http://www.linkedin.com/pub/george-tucker/6/608/3ba
...
http://www.hsph.harvard.edu/alkes-price/
...
http://www.nature.com/ng/journal/v47/n3/full/ng.3190.html
http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/14/299
pdfs/journal.pone.0029095.pdf
pdfs/es201187u.pdf
pdfs/sigtrans.pdf
```